# Do WordPress' cron's clean up expired transients?

Tags: functions, actions, wp-cron, transient

WordPress has a cron named "`delete_expired_transients`" as seen in the image below.

[image]

In this way, does it clean expired **transients** daily?

---

**Or is it just giving us action?**

Should we clean it ourselves in this way according to the hook?

```php
add_action('delete_expired_transients', 'my_custom_fn');

function my_custom_fn()
{
  delete_expired_transients();
}
```

See also: [delete_expired_transients()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_expired_transients/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `delete_expired_transients` is a cron event that runs once per day and the function `delete_expired_transients()` is automatically called when the cron event runs — see [*wp-includes/default-filters.php*](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.6.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L387). So you do not need to call the function manually like you did in your `my_custom_fn()` function.

And if you use a plugin like [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/), you can easily view the cron events in your site and the actions (functions) that will be called when a specific cron event runs.

Comment: Thank you for this nice and descriptive answer. I don't use any plugins so this answer is pretty good enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: So if I ask you a specific question, I wonder if I create a function that performs other functions on a daily basis with the `delete_expired_transients` hook. Does this break the routine of WordPress? Or should I create my own cron?

Comment: `delete_expired_transients` is just a cron event like any other events, so you may add your own action to the event. But depending on what your action does or is for, you might better off use your own cron event instead. You could also remove the default action and call it manually in your function, along with other actions, if you must or just need to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this to provide more background information, but @Sally answer is the more direct answer here since it's too long for a comment.

Although I don't consider myself nearly as talented as many WP Core contributors, I've been actively involved with the WordPress project and beyond for over a decade -- during that time, I can confidently say that the issue of transients in WordPress has probably been one of the more confusing subjects (for everyone), and a headache that has reappeared several times over the years.

The idea of "garbage collecting" transients [was brought up](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20316) over 10 years years ago on Trac. Despite this, [dozens of  similar](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://core.trac.wordpress.org/%20transients) and tangential tickets have been raised since then... one of the biggest problems was that for several years, WP Cron didn't actually call the function to delete expired transients! Around 5 years ago, this was addressed in a [new ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41699) and a job [was added](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/42008) to WP Core cron tasks...

Despite all this, the truth remains muddy. Why? Because so many theme and plugin developers don't understand the proper use of transients, it means that tons of transients in the average WordPress database either don't have expiration dates, should be "options" instead of "transients", and many other things that involve failure to communicate and/or implement best practices.

Plus, there's object caching, which has become increasingly common in recent years. **If you install an object cache like Memcached or Redis on your server, these key/value entities will no longer be stored as "transients" in your MySQL database, but will instead exist in the object cache space, where they might disappear at any given time because of a server reboot or otherwise.**

So what's the best solution? IMO plan for all kinds of user error, and proceed as follows:

1. Delete all transients from your database
2. Install and activate object caching
3. Rely on WP Core to run delete_expired_transients daily

My agency LittleBizzy was one of several other plugin developers with a "Deleted Expired Transients" function; many still exist to this day. Keep in mind that using these plugins WILL NOT properly delete many transients from your database because of issues mentioned above. For this reason, and to ensure a cleaner database, I think it makes more sense to occasionally delete ALL transients and/or purge your object cache.

This is exactly the approach that our free [SlickStack](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/bash/ss-purge-redis.txt) script now takes.

Remember, anything in transients (or object caching) should always be considered temporary non-critical data, so it should always be safe to delete it when needed -- otherwise your code is **doing_it_wrong**.